# Unable to access PhpMyAdmin when cakephp in installed in the server

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to transfer my codes from localhost to a live domain. The directory of the server is like this:

```
-www.example.com
 --app
 --cake
 --vendors
 --plugins
 -- phpMyAdmin
 -- htaccess
```

Since cakephp deals with the URL, when i try to access www.example.com/phpMyAdmin, cakephp complains that "PhpmyAdminController could not be found". I tried to change the htaccess in the app/webroot/htaccess to allow url of phpMyAdmin but it does not work. Can someone help?

I followed the tutorial from the following website: http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2006/08/17/take-over-the-control-of-some-urls-from-cakephp/. However i changed the htaccess in the webroot folder rather than the main folder.

I am really hoping for someone to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by modifying the `.htaccess` file which is located outside app folder.
Please try with this. I'm using this particular code and its working for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    Rewriterule ^phpmyadmin/.*$ - [PT]
    RewriteRule  ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now you'll be able to run a directory like this `http://example.com/phpmyadmin`

Comment: Thanks. It work for me. I am using cake3. I use above code for htaccess which is outside not which is inside the webroot.

Answer (score 1):

you can put the phpMyAdmin folder in app/webroot/ . Access using the same url (with a slash at the end) www.example.com/phpMyAdmin/

Comment: That will work but it is duplicating a approx 17MB of data in the Webroot.

Comment: Instead of copying "17MB of data", you can just symlink from your webroot folder to the current path of phpmyadmin.  Commands: `cd /path/to/cake/php/app/webroot` `ln -s /path/to/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 1):

I guess i had managed to find the answer and the best way to do without duplicating the phpmyadmin will be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(phpMyAdmin)/
   RewriteRule .* - [S=2] 
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The above htaccess must be changed in the root directory of the cake and not the webroot. I do not want to take the credit and the credit goes to the participant of the forum at the following url:

http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Routing-to-an-external-application-td1274772.html