# PhpmyadminController could not be found. CakePHP 2.3.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant, ubuntu-server

I have same problem as the following [**Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446842/unable-to-access-phpmyadmin-when-cakephp-in-installed-in-the-server) but the solution there didn't helped me.

I'm using Vagrant box precise64 (Ubuntu server 12.04) and set there all the required dependencies for CakePHP to work.
The project folder synced with no problem on the server.

Problem is, after installing PHPMyAdmin on the server, and trying to access it from my `localhost:8080/phpmyadmin` I get the following error:

```
Missing Controller
Error: PhpmyadminController could not be found.

Error: Create the class PhpmyadminController below in file: app/Controller/PhpmyadminController.php
```

I've check my .htaccess files, tried to fix with number of solutions (see above as one example) and none seem to work.
I made sure my virtual host allow overwrite to all so if I mess up the .htaccess I get error 500 (like it should be).
Here is my .htaccess content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and even the VirtualHost (under sites-enabled on the server):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName savion.localhost
    ServerAdmin root@savion
    DocumentRoot "/myfinalproject/"

    <Directory "/myfinalproject/">
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can't find a resolution to this issue and will appreciate any help given.

Comment: You should set the `DocumentRoot` of your Directory to your `app/webroot` folder. Which will eliminate the problem of dealing with your `htaccess`.

Comment: Directory also? Or just DocumentRoot change is enough?

Comment: Did that and got 404, in the apache error.log it says: File does not exist: /myfinalproject\xd7

Comment: Then you probably want to make a rule in your htaccess to pass /phpmyadmin through the rewrite.

Comment: after the change I've just did? because previously it didn't work.

Comment: I wonder why he got a downvote on the question. Seems like a clear question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the problem was in a corrupted installation of PHPMyAdmin, re installing it solved the problem.